# MySQL: When is a virtual generated column's value computed?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Let's say that I have a table `t` with 4 normal columns `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4` and 1 virtual computed column, `c1`. If I run the following query:

```
select n1, n2 from t;
```

, is the value of `c1` computed for each row, even though I have not included it in the columns that I am selecting?

According to the offical MySQL documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html :

> VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are
>   read, immediately after any BEFORE triggers.

It says, `rows are read`, not `columns are read`. Hence, the confusion.

To ground this in reality, here is my actual situation:
I am selecting (no where clause) from such a table as described above and it is being really slow (as compared to other similar tables). I am not selecting the computed column, but I am guessing that it is still being computed, causing the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

## Definition of VIRTUAL in MySQL

A column whose values are computed from an expression included in the column definition. Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are read, immediately after any `BEFORE` triggers. A virtual column takes no storage.

> InnoDB supports secondary indexes on generated virtual columns.

**VIRTUAL**: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated virtually when rows are read unlike in *STORED* column where values are evaluated and stored thus requiring disk space. VIRTUAL is evaluated every time

```
select n1, n2 from t;
```

> Here n1 and n2 are **VIRTUAL** columns. They are not stored but are only used until query results persist. Its temporary storage

**In summary**

- Virtual generated columns would not take any disk space.
- Virtual generated columns are `INPLACE` operations which means that the table definition is changed without having to recopy all the data.
- Virtual generated columns the values are calculated on the fly during the reading operation and BEFORE triggers.